# How to use a proc to format groupdate keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand how the format option works in the groupdate gem.

The readme explains that `format` takes a string that is passed to strftime or a proc ([here](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#user-content-pretty-keys)).

I'm having trouble understanding the `proc` part of this.

A simple example, if `User.group_by_month(:created_at).count.keys` returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` (i.e., months of the year), how would I do a simple transformation of these keys, say `key * 2`?

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/lib/groupdate/magic.rb), format appears to be expecting a method

```
if options[:format].respond_to?(:call)
  options[:format]
end
```

So I would have expected to be able to do something like `User.group_by_month(:created_at, format: 'Proc.new { |d| d * 2 }')....`

But this returns only `Proc.new { |d| d * 2}` as a string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're passing the Proc as a string. What if you remove the single quotes around `Proc.new { |d| d * 2 }`?

Comment: @user12341234 that was indeed the problem, can't believe I overlooked that. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Glad that worked! Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `*_by` methods expect `Proc`s (or `lambda`s or blocks) as arguments. It looks like you are accidentally wrapping your `Proc` literal in quotes, making it a string. Try removing the quotes to turn it back into a `Proc`, like so:

```
User.group_by_month(:created_at, format: Proc.new { |d| d * 2 })
```